# How to undo git stash --all

Tags: git

I just did a

```
git stash --all
```

because I wanted to stash also ignored files. Now I know it was stupid, because in my .gitignore file I had also a directory with tons of important files in it. (I did this in production)

How can I undo this?

```
git stash show -p
```

just shows me files which are not in gitignore. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: `git stash pop` or `git stash apply` will restore all your file even the ignored ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same way you would in another situation, i.e. just do:

```
git stash pop
```

or

```
git stash apply
```

Git stash show -p is not showing you any diff regarding the ignored files, because none of those files that had previously been git ignored are in the index, so there's nothing to diff against. So that's normal.

Comment: `git stash apply` is my preferred command, as it does not remove the stash itself.

Comment: Thanx!! `git stash apply` did it